# Permission Level to hide the option in share file "People in Organisation with link can edit"

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-permissions

I would like to Hide the option "People in Organisation with link can edit" and user should be able to send or share link with Specific user.

Right now i have special permission for that i have "grayed out" the option "People in Organisation with link can edit" and when it comes to sending link by selecting "specify user", it sends an approval to site owner which i do not want SharePoint to send the approval email. Though i need to send the user directly to another user.

Please let me know, if i have missed to select any permission in permission Levels.

Appreciate your support !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution first: You can use PowerShell to disable ***People in your organization* sharing links** in a site:

```
Set-SPOSite -Identity <SiteURL> -DisableCompanyWideSharingLinks 1
```

Note that you need to be a Global admin or SharePoint admin to run the command.

Turn “**Allow access requests**” **off** via *Settings* > *Site permissions* > *Change how members can share* to avoid sending approval emails to Site Owners.

---

Explanation:

You are seeing this behavior because the site has limited sharing site while "**Allow access requests**" enabled under "**Site sharing settings**".

[image]

While using default permission levels, the "**People in organization with the link**" and "**Specific people**" options are both available without approval when user has at least **Contribute** permission in a library. Users who have **Read** permission (or less) will need approval from Admins to do the sharing.

Reference: [Limit sharing in Microsoft 365.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/solutions/microsoft-365-limit-sharing?view=o365-worldwide#people-in-your-organization-sharing-links)

Comment: Thank you for the script, i have couple of questions 1.does script disable to all permission levels (site admin, Owner, Mem) 2. How to remove permanently "Web-Only Limited access" from Site Permission

Comment: @striker92 1. Yes, the script disables the link on a site level, for all user roles. 2. The “Web-Only Limited access" permission is a system permission managed by SharePoint and cannot be removed/deleted in a site. You can only remove this permission from a user by changing the permission inheritance or reset user permission on a higher level.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it was really helpful.

Comment: @striker92 Would you please give it a vote or accept it as answer if you find the reply helpful? It will help others in this forum to find answers quickly as well. Thanks.